# How do I activate the chrome's cookie function on local files

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cookies

I'm using the "jQuery Cookie Plugin" on my homepage but it doesn't work in only chrome. And I use only chrome too. help please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find that using raw JavaScript rather than a plugin to achieve such a simple task will be faster and easier to manage cross-browsers.

The below code works in Chrome.

```
// Thanks to http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html for the below functions
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful Shitic? Let me know if it's not what you needed and I'll adjust the answer for you.

Comment: -1 Cookies don't work on local files in Chrome regardless of the use of raw JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem and solved it this terrible solution,
using store and cookie plugin together.

```
<script src="js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="js/jquery.Storage.js" type="text/javascript">


var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;


//get cookies
var myCookie=(is_chrome)?$.Storage.get("helpFlag"):$.cookies.get("helpFlag");

//set cookies
if(is_chrome)$.Storage.set("helpFlag", "1");else $.cookies.set("helpFlag", "1");
```

I know that this isn't perfect but works for me.